# Identificar y leer un array

Tags: php, array

La respuesta enviada por un WS es la variable

```
$respuesta['mensajesValidacion']
```

la paso por el `var_dump` y me da la siguiente informacion:

```
object(stdClass)#28 (1) {
  ["string"]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(98) "Fatal:[FAU04]- (R) Monto Incluyendo Impuesto 4.427E6 diferente del valor bruto total de la factura"
    [1]=>
    string(41) " sumado a los cargos totales a la facutra"
    [2]=>
    string(60) " y restado de los descuentos totales a la factura : 4.522E6 "
    [3]=>
    string(121) "Fatal: [FAY10]- (R) Rechazo: Si reporta una tarifa '2.50' diferente para uno de los tributos enunciados en la tabla 5.3.9"
  }
}
{
    "codigo":110,
    "consecutivoDocumento":"",
    "esValido":false,
    "mensaje":"El documento no superado.",
    "mensajesValidacion":{
        "string":[
            "Fatal:[FAU04]- (R) Monto Incluyendo Impuesto 4.427E6 diferente del valor bruto total de la factura",
            " sumado a los cargos totales a la facutra",
            " y restado de los descuentos totales a la factura : 4.522E6 ",
            "Fatal: [FAY10]- (R) Rechazo: Si reporta una tarifa '2.50' diferente para uno de los tributos enunciados en la tabla 5.3.9"
        ]},
        "nombre":null,
        "reglasNotificacion":null,
        "reglasValidacion":null,
        "resultado":null,
        "success":false
}
```

deseo saber que tipo de array es y como puedo recuperar la clave y el valor de cada uno de los elementos. Gracias

Comment: Para estar completamente seguro. Lo que has plasmado aca es lo mismo solo que en 2 variantes ? porque no me cuadra la parte que esta después del `string(121)` ya que tienes las cualidades de un `json` y no de un `array` de php.

Comment: Asi es, la recorro con ´foreach´ y muestsra lo mismo...

Comment: Me suena que eso no es un *array*, sino una instancia de clase. Por el `object` del principio.

Comment: En el var_dump te lo esta diciendo es un objeto stdClass. para acceder a sus propiedades utiliza `->` por ejemplo para la primera de ellas: `$respuesta['mensajesValidacion']->string[0]`. Si lo que estas recibiendo es una respuesta en JSON y utilizas `json_decode` tambien puedes pasar `true` en el segundo argumento, para que convierta los objetos en arrays asociativos, ej: `json_decode($my_json, true)`

Comment: Como ya se ha dicho, el WS está devolviendo un JSON, y por tanto debes leerlo usando la notación `$TuObjeto->clave`, por eso el `var_dump` te dice `object(stdClass)` y no `array`. Luego en `mensajesValidacion` sí hay un array en la clave llamada `string`. De todos modos, y no por criticar, ese WS está mal programado, porque eso no debería ser un array en sí, eso en términos reales debería ser una simple cadena, ¿programaron el WS para que divida los saltos de línea como si fueran elementos de un array? Está raro eso.

Comment: Muy acertado Tu comentario  @A. Cedano, junto con el de Xerif... esta la respuesta correcta

Answer (score 0):

El array que buscas esta en la propiedad **string** del objeto **mensajesValidacion** por lo que algo así te servirá:

```
foreach( $respuesta['mensajesValidacion']->string as $key => $value){ var_dump($key, value )}
```